# Reading XMP data using ImageMagick in Perl

Tags: image, perl, image-processing, imagemagick, xmp

I am looking for a way to extract XMP data from an image file using ImageMagick.

I know how to extract that data using the commandline:

```
convert -ping my_image.jpg xmp:xmp-profile.xml
```

But i need a way to do it using the ImageMagick Perl API.

**How can this be done? Any suggestions?**

Comment: I haven't got time to check this minute, but I think it works the same as IPTC data... http://stackoverflow.com/a/26014887/2836621

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the image info using Image::Magick perl module.

```
 use Image::Magick;
 my $im = Image::Magick->new();
 $im->Read('/path/to/image');
 print $im->Identify();
```

Or if you are not bound by image magick you could use Image::ExifTool;

```
my $exif_tool = Image::ExifTool->new();
my $info = $exif_tool->ImageInfo('/path/to/image'); #retrieves all image data
# my $info = $exif_tool->ImageInfo('/path/to/image', ['xmp:*']); retrieves only xmp

use Data::Dumper;
warn Dumper $info;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$code = `convert -ping my_image.jpg xmp:xmp-profile.xml`;
```

Comment: thanks for your contribution (i know how to use backticks), but i am looking for a way to do it using the Perl Imagemagick API